# Calculate the multiplicative inverse of large numbers using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the multiplicative inverse of a large number mod another large number. For example, I want to calculate the multiplicative inverse of 6003722857 mod 77695236973. I wrote some C++ code to do this. It works fine for small numbers like a = 1891 and n = 3797 but once I try very large numbers, the program doesn't work. There is no error. It looks like it is calculating something but then the program just ends.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  long long int a = 0, n = 0;
  cout << "Enter a: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Enter n: ";
  cin >> n;

  for (long long int c = 1; c < n; c++) {
   long long int num = a*c - 1;
    if (num%n == 0) {
      cout << "The multiplicative inverse is " << c << "." << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably overflowing the variables. Try using a "bignum" library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: How are you running the program? (and what are you compiling it with?) "just ends" seems like a surprising outcome. For me (using VS2013), it just hangs, as might be expected when crawling over such a huge search space.

Comment: If the program "just ends", could it be that c >= n?  If that wasn't expected to happen, it may be as @JoachimPileborg suggests.

Comment: It works, but it is very slow. Is there no way to run the problem in multiple threads? Which input did you use which caused the problem?

Comment: [Works so far for `56757656857555855678` as input!](http://ideone.com/kfYpep) Define _'very large numbers'_ more clearly please!

Comment: The exact numbers I am trying to calculate are 6003722857 mod 77695236973 where a = 6003722857 and n = 77695236973. I am running this program in a terminal. I am on a mac. I use the command emac mult_inv.cc to edit the file, I use make multi_inv to build it, and I use ./mult_inv to run it. The answer it should spit out is 77695236753 so c>=n shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I have considered using GMP but I was thinking that might be a little bit of an overkill as most of the time, this program will be working with small numbers.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That doesn't work because it is doing exactly what I am describing is the problem... You have given the program input and it just ended without giving you any output.

Comment: @A.Wong It does what it is expected to do. Your condition `(num%n == 0)` is likely not doing what you expect it to do. Use a debugger to check what's actually going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here it is in super-fast c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

using temp_t = std::tuple<long long, long long>;

long long calcInverse(long long a, long long n)
{
    long long t = 0, newt = 1;
    long long r = n, newr = a;  
    while (newr != 0) {
        auto quotient = r /newr;
        tie(t, newt) = make_tuple(newt, t- quotient * newt);
        tie(r, newr) = make_tuple(newr, r - quotient * newr);
    }
    if (r > 1)
        throw runtime_error("a is not invertible");
    if (t < 0)
        t += n;
    return t;
}

int main ()
{
  long long int a = 6003722857 , n = 77695236973;
/*
  cout << "Enter a: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Enter n: ";
  cin >> n;
  */
  try {
    auto inverse = calcInverse(a, n);
    cout << "The multiplicative inverse is " << inverse << endl;
  }
  catch(exception& e) {
      cout << e.what() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just realised that the definition of temp_t is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have my own version of the extended Euclidean algorithm although not as clean as yours.

Comment: Worst case set of numbers are the two largest fibonacci numbers: < 2^63 a = 4660046610375530309 , n = 7540113804746346429 , which will take 90 loops. In this case, (1/a mod n) == a. The largest prime < 2^63 is 2^63-25 = 9223372036854775783, which will have an inverse for every number 1 to 9223372036854775782 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extended Euclid algorithm to do this:

[Wiki - extended Euclidean algorithm - modular integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers)